# What are the WCF bindings Silverlight supports?

Tags: silverlight, wcf, silverlight-4.0

I am using Silverlight to develop my applications...

My concern is **what are the bindings** Silverlight will support (when consuming WCF services)?

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc896571%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) you have full description of supported WCF features by Silverlight 4.